# Form is not set to null after submitting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-functional-component

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem. I'm using Firebase for SignUp with Email and Password. But while using this I'm getting some issues:-

1. Form is not set to null after submission(may be it ends up with catch block).
2. displayName sets to null while saving creds into the FireStore(sometimes it saves into the db and sometimes not).

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './Pages/HomePage/Homepage.component';
import ShopComponent from './Pages/Shop/shop.component';
import Header from './Components/Headers/header.component';
import {Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {auth} from './Components/FireBase/firebase.util';
import {createUserProfileDocument} from './Components/FireBase/firebase.util';

import SignInAndSignUpPage from './Pages/Sign-In and Sign-Up/sign-in-and-sign-up.component';

function App() {
  const [user,setUser] =useState(null);

  useEffect(
    ()=>{
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const signal = abortController.signal;


 
auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
  if (userAuth) { 
    const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
    userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => { 
      setUser({
       
          id: snapShot.id,
          ...snapShot.data()
        }
      ,()=>console.log(user,App.js));

      
    });
  }
})
return function cleanup()
{
    abortController.abort();
} 
},[]);

    function logout()
  {
     setUser(null);
   }
  return (

<div>
  <Header user={user} logout={logout}/>
  <Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
  <Route path="/shop" component={ShopComponent} />
  <Route path="/signin" component={SignInAndSignUpPage}/>
  </Switch>
  {console.log(user)}
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**SignUp.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import FormInput from '../FormInput/FormInput.component';
import CustomButton from '../custom-button/custom-button.component';

import { auth, createUserProfileDocument } from '../FireBase/firebase.util';
import {useState} from 'react';

import './sign-up.styles.scss';

export default function SignUp() {

    const [User,setUser] = useState({
  displayName: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  confirmPassword: ''
});


  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();



if (User.password !== User.confirmPassword) {
  alert("passwords don't match");
      return;
}
console.log(User);
try {
  const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    User.email,
    User.password,
    
  ).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    return result.user.updateProfile({
      displayName: User.displayName
    })
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
console.log(user);

  await createUserProfileDocument(user,User.displayName);
  
  setUser({
    displayName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: ""
  });
  console.log(User);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
  };

  function handleChange(event) {
const { name, value } = event.target;

setUser({...User,[name]:value});
  };

return (
  <div className='sign-up'>
    <h2 className='title'>I do not have a account</h2>
    <span>Sign up with your email and password</span>
    <form className='sign-up-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FormInput
        type='text'
        name='displayName'
        value={User.displayName}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        label='Display Name'
        required
      />
      <FormInput
        type='email'
        name='email'
        value={User.email}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        label='Email'
        required
      />
      <FormInput
        type='password'
        name='password'
        value={User.password}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        label='Password'
        required
      />
      <FormInput
        type='password'
        name='confirmPassword'
        value={User.confirmPassword}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        label='Confirm Password'
        required
      />
      <CustomButton type='submit'>SIGN UP</CustomButton>
    </form>
  </div>
    );

}
```

**Firebase.util.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCeHYh9WYswWRO69UF8wjTfhK8YXdc7M10",
    authDomain: "clothingecom-signin.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://clothingecom-signin.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "clothingecom-signin",
    storageBucket: "clothingecom-signin.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "150267270963",
    appId: "1:150267270963:web:e188327556e8ffbb099046",
    measurementId: "G-Z1CVYEVYKN"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);



export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
  if (!userAuth) return; 

   console.log(userAuth);
  const snapShot = await userRef.get();
   console.log(userRef);
   console.log(snapShot);
  if (!snapShot.exists) { 
    const {displayName,  email } = userAuth; 
    const createdAt = new Date();
    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt,
        ...additionalData
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error creating user', error.message);
    }
  }

  return userRef;
};

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    return result.user.updateProfile({
      displayName: User.displayName
    })
    this.setState({
     displayName: "",
     email: "",
     password: "",
     confirmPassword: ""
    });
  })
```